# Where can I find math.h fucntion erf implementation

Tags: c, math

I want to see how function: `erf` or `erfc` is implemented in math library in C. Does anyone know how I could find the source code?

Comment: Decide which implementation you want (Who made yours?), download their runtime library sources, run `grep`.

Comment: not necessary, OP can search online

Answer (score 0):

You have to check one of the implementations. You can download sources to your machine or check available online sources, i.e:

http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/math/tgmath.h#L387

Comment: link is a 404. can you update the answer? do you have an archived version? or a copy?

Comment: The above linked to a glibc implementation, so you can try finding glibc source instead. For example, https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_erf.c (Sun) or https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ia64/fpu/s_erf.S (Intel).